# Bootstrap table td color change based on value

Tags: jquery, css

```html
<table data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-show-columns="true" data-show-pagination-switch="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-key-events="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-resizable="true" data-cookie="true" data-cookie-id-table="saveId" data-show-export="true" data-click-to-select="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Birthday</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php foreach($people as $person) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $person["name"]; ?></td>
        <td id="birthday"><?=$person["birthday"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $person["address"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to change the text color in birthday td using jquery.

If a birthday is within a week, the text color is in green.

If it passed, its text color is in red.

How can I get a value in birthday td?

Comment: There are a couple of matters here: 1. what is the date format? The year does not need to be present. (our company's employee birthday does not include the year when shown, only month and day) 2. if there will (eventually) be more table rows, then birthday cannot be an `id` attribute, as there can only be 1 element with this id value in a HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your date format.
Is this just one birthday per page? because I would recommend you to use a class in place to an ID to make it more flexible. Anyways, You can do the following.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  //Get the birthday
  var birthday = $('#birthday').text();
  //Convert it to Date
  var dateBirthday = new Date(birthday);
  //Get today to compare
  var today = new Date();
  //Get rid of the hour from today
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0)
  
  // To calculate the time difference of two dates 
  var Difference_In_Time = dateBirthday.getTime() - today.getTime(); 

  // To calculate the no. of days between two dates 
  var Difference_In_Days = Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
  
  //Check if 7 days left AND the date is not past
  if( Difference_In_Days < 7 && Difference_In_Days > 0 ){
   $('#birthday').addClass('one-week-or-less');
  }else{
    $('#birthday').addClass('more-than-one-week-or-past');
  }

});
```

```css
.one-week-or-less{
   color:green;
}
.more-than-one-week-or-past{
   color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-show-columns="true" data-show-pagination-switch="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-key-events="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-resizable="true" data-cookie="true" data-cookie-id-table="saveId" data-show-export="true" data-click-to-select="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Birthday</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td id="birthday" class='one-week-or-less'>2020-07-28</td>
        <td>Street</td>
        </tr>
        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I used [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript/) source to compare dates